LM3478 MOSFET and inductors overheating
I'm trying to design a SEPIC converter based on LM3478, with input voltage range 12-36 V, and output 24 V 2 A. I'm calculated all relevant values of components, according to "AN-1484 Designing A SEPIC Converter" and LM3478 Datasheet, and the results was quite similar with examples provided, also I tried to use Webench, but its values we're far beyond mine and example's, so I ignored it. Anyway, after the assembly, I'm stuck with the problem, that converter holds output voltage at +/- 24 V, but under load of 1.8 A (LED driver at the output holds current), both of inductors and MOSFET quickly overheating, in, like, 30 seconds.
In this way I burned two MOSFETs, because I haven't noticed, that diode became shorted in some reason too, so, I changed MOSFET, and burned second one. Also, I noticed that in case of input voltage is 24 V and more (buck mode), with no load, MOSFET heats in pulses (like, sharply became hot, and then cooling down and repeat), and current on my lab power supply synchronously jumps to 0.2-0.3 A and goes back to zero (I haven't noticed this effect in boost mode, when VIN lower than 24V). So, here is the question, is there root of problem in poor PCB design, or there is some fundamental miscalculation, that I don't see? I re-read different datasheets and appnotes, and many topics on forum, but I still haven't clear solution.
Here's schematic, L1 and L2 have L=10 uH, DCR=30 mΩ, Irms=7.8 A, Isat=8.5 A, MOSFET is Infineon BSC0702LS.

And PCB (all layers)

PCB's bottom (SEPIC located here)

PCB's top (here located LED driver, opamp and MCU)

Waveform of L2 (input inductor) at 21.7 V. At this moment, converter in boost mode, and if I'm lowering the input voltage on lab supply, quantity of pulses rises, and if I'm increasing input, pulses count becoming lower until 24 V, and after switching to buck mode, I assume, increasing again (and in buck mode MOSFET starting to overheat, with no load).

Waveworm of L3 (output inductor), same behaviour.

MOSFET gate, same behaviour.

Gate on 24 V input

Gate on 26 V input

Gate on 28 V input

Gate on 30 V input

I'm wondering, why in boost mode, when VIN < 24 V, quantity of pulses on gate increasing and decreasing slowly, but after VIN > 24 V it became superfast, like increasing VIN for 0.1 V doubles the pulses count.

Some connections are missing in your PCB images. Could you please put all the layers separately?

I've added some detailed PCB drawings

Why did you not use coupled coils for the inductors?

Because it's just simplier....Is it possibly can be critical issue?

Please provide a data sheet link for the inductors.

FXL1040-100-M https://www.lcsc.com/datasheet/lcsc_datasheet_2305161117_cjiang--Changjiang-Microelectronics-Tech-FXL1040-100-M_C475915.pdf

There are no planes or pours? 2 layer design? Please confirm?

I've updated drawings of PCB, yes, it's 2-layer, but ground planes were hidden, I thought without them PCB'll be more readable

Your design appears to be suffering from sub-harmonic oscillations.  There is an excellent discussion of this in the LM3748 data sheet (https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm3478.pdf?ts=1712269524043&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FLM3478).  Because your worst-case duty cycle is high, it may require external slope compensation in addition to the compensation supplied by the part.  I would double-check the calculated values of C13 and C14, and then see if there is enough compensation.
A couple of other possible issues:
Referring to AN-1484, and applying equations 1 through 4, it looks like your inductor value is lower than the application note recommends for your switching frequency. This might be solved by increasing the values of the inductors or increasing the switching frequency.
Also, I am unfamiliar with the LM3478, but your MOSFET has a relatively high gate capacitance.  I would put a probe on the gate and see if you are switching cleanly, although from your photos I can't see any ringing.

Mr. Birckhead, thank you for your response, after manipulations with compensation circuit, and inductor, I came to the same conclusion - for fast-switching dc/dc converter it was my mistake to select MOSFET mainly from lowest Rdson, while gate charge plays much more important role, and yes, after reviewing calculations, I think, something should be bigger - inductor or switching frequency. Also, I'm thinking about tying to rebuild SEPIC with different IC, in particular with LM5155, because it has calculator from TI (maybe i was wrong in my Mathcad calculations).
